# Highstock dateTimeLabelFormats doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to show only the first day of the month in Xaxis, everything is ok when
the series array has more than or equal to five elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6Ne/

```
data: [
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1), 10.82413772161932 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 1, 1), 0.10286926951274679 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 2, 1), 0.4359489916094994 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 3, 1), 0.4359489916094994 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 4, 1), 0.4359489916094994 ]
    ]
```

But when the series are fewer than five elements the dateTimeLabelFormats option doesn't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/XtFnx/

```
  data: [
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1), 10.82413772161932 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 1, 1), 0.10286926951274679 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 2, 1), 0.4359489916094994 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2014, 3, 1), 0.4359489916094994 ]
    ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What am I looking for? They look similar to me.

Comment: I think OP is asking how to show first day of the month on x-axis. I 'think'...

Comment: If so, it isn't working in any of the JSFiddles provided.

Comment: Yes, you can see that it doesn't work in JSFiddles. The only difference is the size of the series.

Comment: But you said "everything is ok when the series array has more than or equal to five elements" -- but now you're saying it's not okay? At this point I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: The problem is when the given array has fewer then five elements.
If you check the two links above you can see the difference in the Xaxis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected: you have changed month/year options, but all others (day, hour etc.) are used as defaults. dateTimeLabelFormats doesn't prevent from displaying different interval on xAxis. To change that use [minTickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minTickInterval).

Answer (score 2):

While I"m not sure what you are asking, but have I vaguely guessed that you want to show first of each month on x-axis. If yes, you can use tickPositioner.

```
tickPositioner: function() {

                     var ticks = [
                    Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
                    Date.UTC(2014, 1, 1), 
                    Date.UTC(2014, 2, 1), 
                    Date.UTC(2014, 3, 1)];
                    //dates.info defines what to show in labels
                    //apparently dateTimeLabelFormats is always ignored when specifying tickPosistioner

                     ticks.info = {
                    //unitName: "month", 
                    unitName: "day",
                    higherRanks: {} // Omitting this would break things
                };           
                return ticks;
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6Ne/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/XtFnx/3/